ModSecurity Mutex Permission Denied

ModSecurity: collection_retrieve_ex: Failed to lock proc mutex: Permission denied [hostname "filip

Please advice how do resolve this issue, all of sites what error on this.
almalinux8
ispmanager
apache MPM-ITK 2.4.37
PHP 7.4
ModSec 2
Have trying search and try change to 755 but not help.

is SELinux enabled (i hope it is)?  Did you check the audit logs?
Permissions mean nothing without sharing the owner and group and selinux context.  Remember the parent directories' ownerships matter, too.
